# WPF MVVM where i need to put my converters?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I need to write a value converter. Something like this:

```
public class HostStatusToDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool)value == true ? "Статус сервера: Подключён" : "Статус сервера: Недоступен";
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
    }
}
```

Where i need to put it using MVVM pattern? In Model folder? Or create a folder Converters?

Comment: Are you sure this should not be part of some viewmodel?

Comment: I've always considered converters to being part of the view, or at most the view model - they're just another technique for formatting data retrieved from the model like any other. That being said, I usually create a Converters folder somewhere close to the view.

Comment: For myself, I create a folder `Converters` and stored there. I think that the converters must be on the side `View`, because they are there working.

Comment: Did the answers sufficiently helped you understand your problem or do is there still something unclear?

Answer (score 14):

Technically, the Converter are part of the View and hence the View Logic.  and that's how you should treat it imho.

[BooleanToVisibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a good example. In your `ViewModel` you'd only have a boolean property (visible or not), cause your ViewModel has no knowledge of your UI/View.

For example, in one UI (for example Desktop) you may want to "Convert" the boolean to an Text (i.e. "Success" and "Failure"), in other UI (Win8 App) you may want to have boolean to convert to a check/cross icon.

This means, that this logic (check/cross or "Success"/"Failure") do not belong to your ViewModel class and strictly is very specific to the UI/View of your application and hence the only logical place to use it would be the View-Project (assuming you have at least 3 different projects for Model, ViewModel and View respectively).

**Edit:** To extend my example on `BooleanToVisibility` from above: 
As you can see from the namespaces, it's in `System.Windows.Controls.BooleanToVisibilityConverter` which is where the controls are placed in, which are pure `View` classes.

Also, more importantly, the Converter classes are tightly specific to WPF, a certain UI framework. If you use any other UI framework, this classes are useless. Hence, they don't belong neither to Model or ViewModel. View is the only logical place to put them in.

Answer (score 3):

View model *is* a value converter itself.

You don't need perform such conversions in a separate class. Just create appropriate property, something like `HostStatusDescription`, and bind your controls to this property instead of boolean one.

Comment: This is the best answer and it should've being accepted

Answer (score 0):

The folder or not is a code destribution question. So chooce on your preference.

Converter itself goes like a separate class, like in your case, its definition ends up in XAML of a control when it is going to be applied, and it's instance is declared in the markup of the control's binding specification.

Follow example link : [Value Converters](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)